# How to run python unittests repeatedly from a script and collect results

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I cannot figure out how to run single unit tests from within a python script and collect the results.

Scenario: I have a battery of tests that check various methods producing various statistical distributions of different objects. The tests sometimes fail, as they should given that I am basically checking for particular kinds of randomness. I would like to run the tests repeatedly from a script or even from the interpreter and collect results for further analysis.

Suppose I have a module myTest.py with:

```
class myTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
       ...building objects, etc....
    def testTest1(self):
           ..........
    def testTest2(self):
           ..........
```

Basically I need to:

1. run the setup method
2. run testTest1 (say), 100 times
3. collect the failures
4. return the failures

The closest I got to was (using code from a similar question):

```
from unittest import TextTestRunner, TestSuite
runner = TextTestRunner(verbosity = 2)
tests = ['testTest1']
suite = unittest.TestSuite(map(myTest, tests))
runner.run(suite)
```

But this does not work, because:

`runner.run(suite)`   does not run the setup method

and

I cannot catch the exception it throws when testTest1 fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need to add the test that you want to run multiple times to the suite.

Here is a complete code example. You can also [see this code running in an interactive Python console to prove that it does actually work](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/5244147/gistfile1.py/ipython2/).

```
import unittest
import random

class NullWriter(object):
    def write(*_, **__):
        pass

    def flush(*_, **__):
        pass

SETUP_COUNTER = 0

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        global SETUP_COUNTER
        SETUP_COUNTER += 1

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertTrue(random.random() > 0.3)

    def test_two(self):
        # We just want to make sure this isn't run
        self.assertTrue(False, "This should not have been run")


def suite():
    tests = []
    for _ in range(100):
        tests.append('test_one')

    return unittest.TestSuite(map(MyTestCase, tests))

results = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=NullWriter()).run(suite())
print dir(results)
print 'setUp was run', SETUP_COUNTER, 'times'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves part of my problem: running the test(s) a number of times. It does not solve the second part: catching the exception(s) thrown by self.AssertTrue and computing some statistics on it. I guess I am really trying to force unittests to do something they are not meant to, in a sense. Instead of having them run autonomously, I'd like to have them report their results to my script. It's probably a better idea to replace the assertTrue statements with conditional assignments, and then work on those.

Comment: The assertion errors are already getting caught by unittest It really sounds like you just want to run a function 100 times in a loop, gather the output in a list and then analyse the results. Having said that though, you can suppress the output to sys.stderr by specifying another file like object to the stream argument in the test runner. Then you can do whatever you want with the results. Again, have a look at the interactive console.

Comment: You are right, I am really trying to have a function run a loop over the tests---and I was trying to avoid having duplicate code (since I want to keep the tests). I'll look into passing a a different stream-like arg to the test runner, thanks for the suggestion.